# Is there a problem with using <xsl:key> for validation?

Tags: validation, xslt, key, xslt-2.0

I find myself using lots and lots of keys and sometimes I put sanity checks in them, like:

```
<xsl:key name="foo-with-bar" match="foo[contains(., 'bar')]">
  <xsl:if test="@baz='xyz'">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
      Can't handle &lt;foo> containing "bar" if @baz="xyz"
    </xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
</xsl:key>
```

(This is actually a pretty simple test - the actual tests can be quite complex.) Which made me think, why not use keys in cases where I don't actually need a key but only a sanity check?  E.g:

```
<xsl:key name="sanity-check" match="foo[contains(., 'bar')][@baz='xyz']">
  <xsl:message terminate="yes">
    Can't handle &lt;foo> containing "bar" if @baz="xyz"
  </xsl:message>
</xsl:key>
```

I realize that Saxon will not terminate unless I actually use the key, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sanity-check', '')"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, can I be sure that an XSLT processor will actually terminate with this pattern?  I guess this is not how keys were designed to be used.

### Background: Less attractive alternatives (ignore if tl;dr)

I realize that Schematron could be an alternative to this approach, but as these tests might not be about document validity but whether the stylesheet is able to process the document, I find tests that are implemented by the stylesheet itself quite attractive.

Another alternative might be to use templates instead of keys.  I see two options here:

1. Testing-and-terminating templates overrule "normal" templates during regular processing. However, during regular processing, not all nodes that need to be tested are necessarily processed by a template match that can be overruled.
2. A separate testing run using templates, like so:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="sanity-check"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="actual-processing"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="sanity-check">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="sanity-check"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template mode="sanity-check" match="foo[contains(., 'bar')][@baz='xyz']">
     <xsl:message terminate="yes">
       foo containing bar can't have @baz set to xyz
     </xsl:message>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

Keys still have an advantage because more complex checks that can't be expressed in a simple pattern are possible without extra effort.  With templates, this would require constructs like this:

```
<xsl:template mode="sanity-check" match="foo">
  <xsl:variable name="variable" select="some-complicated-expression"/>
  <xsl:if test="some-test-requiring[$variable=@bar]">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
      Fail!
    </xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="sanity-check" select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

There are two disadvantages here:

1. More boilerplate code required.  If we make a mistake there, tests will not be performed correctly, but we won't notice.  We need:

   - the "identity transform" like template
   - `<xsl:apply-templates mode="sanity-check" select="node()|@*"/>` in each template containing more complex tests.
2. Problems with overlapping tests, e.g. one with `match="A|B"`, another with `match="B|C"`, both requiring some `<xsl:choose>`/`<xsl:if>` to decide if we need to terminate. An element `<B>` will only match one of the templates.  With keys, there's no need to worry about overlapping matches.

Comment: Is there some reason it wouldn't be better to do schema validation on the input and output messages?

Comment: @DanField Simple schema validation will not do, but as I wrote, Schematron would be an option. Being able to perform some checks that can be done conveniently, efficiently and without requiring another processing step and another piece of software (or Schematron compilation step) just seems nice. Apart from that, this is also a more general question about in what ways keys may be leveraged.